# Selecting unique values without repeating colums

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a very specific question: I have a set of observations, from a number of subjects, along several years (only one observation per year). I want to select only one observation of each individual, (I don't care from which year) in a way that I end up with a similar number of observations per year, and as random as possible.

So, starting from `df` in which 1 are years there is an observation for that individual, and 0 are years where there's no observation for that individual:

```
df <- data.frame(Ind   = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"),
             Year1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
             Year2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
             Year3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
             Year4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

which looks like

[image: df example View]

I'd like to end up with something like this

[image: df2 example View]

*EDIT: trying to apply solutions proposed (and failing)*

**(1) earch's answer:**

```
df <- as_tibble(df)

year.weights <- df %>% 
  gather(Year, Obs, -Ind) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarize(wt = sum(Obs)) %>% 
  ungroup


df %>% 
      gather(Year, Obs, -Ind) %>%
      filter(Obs == 1) %>% 
      left_join(year.weights, by = "Year") %>% 
      group_by(Ind) %>% 
      sample_n(1, weight = 1 / wt) %>% 
      select(-wt) %>% 
      spread(Year, Obs) %>% 
      ungroup
```

This gives an error `Error: 'by' can't contain join column 'Year' which is missing from RHS` which appears in the `left_join` step. I try to solve this by giving the name "Year" to the only variable in RHS

`names(year.weights) <- "Year"`

But now this gives a new error: `Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : Can't join on 'Year' x 'Year' because of incompatible types (numeric / character)` which actually makes a lot of sense as Year column in LHS contains Year1, Year2, Year3, etc. while Year column in RHS contains the number 27.

This is as far as I got because I can't see what earch was trying to accomplish, but I do believe a feasible solution can be achieved through this n_sample and the weight argument, but I can't quite see it yet.

**(2) Mikey's answer:**

This works well (I don't get the error I was getting before) but it doesn't guarantee that I'll get an equal (or similar) number of 1s for each "Year" column.

So, if I run the code a couple of times for testing, I get:

```
# first time
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1
 [2,]    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    1    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1
 [8,]    0    1    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    0    1

# second time
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    1
 [6,]    1    0    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    1
 [9,]    0    0    0    1
[10,]    0    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    1    0
```

**(3) Andre Elrico's answer:**

It has the same problem as answer (2), it doesn't guarantee an equal number of 1s for each Year: see two random outputs:

```
# fist try
   Ind Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
1    a    NA    NA    NA     1
2    b    NA    NA     1    NA
3    c    NA    NA     1    NA
4    d    NA     1    NA    NA
5    e     1    NA    NA    NA
6    f    NA    NA     1    NA
7    g     1    NA    NA    NA
8    h    NA    NA    NA     1
9    i    NA    NA    NA     1
10   j    NA    NA    NA     1
11   k    NA    NA     1    NA

# second try
   Ind Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
1    a     1    NA    NA    NA
2    b     1    NA    NA    NA
3    c    NA    NA     1    NA
4    d    NA    NA     1    NA
5    e    NA     1    NA    NA
6    f    NA    NA    NA     1
7    g    NA    NA    NA     1
8    h    NA    NA    NA     1
9    i    NA    NA    NA     1
10   j    NA     1    NA    NA
11   k    NA    NA     1    NA
```

**(4) paoloeusebi's answer** has the same problem as the previous ones. Not guaranteeing equal number of selected 1s per row:

```
# first try
   Ind Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
1    a     1    NA    NA    NA
2    b    NA    NA    NA     0
3    c    NA    NA     1    NA
4    d    NA    NA    NA     0
5    e    NA    NA     1    NA
6    f    NA    NA    NA     1
7    g     1    NA    NA    NA
8    h    NA    NA     0    NA
9    i    NA    NA    NA     1
10   j    NA    NA    NA     1
11   k    NA    NA     1    NA

# second try
   Ind Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
1    a    NA    NA    NA     1
2    b    NA     0    NA    NA
3    c    NA     1    NA    NA
4    d    NA    NA    NA     0
5    e    NA    NA    NA     1
6    f    NA     0    NA    NA
7    g    NA     0    NA    NA
8    h    NA    NA     0    NA
9    i    NA    NA     0    NA
10   j    NA    NA     0    NA
11   k    NA     0    NA    NA
```

Comment: do you only want to randomly select years with a value of `1`?

Comment: In your example, individual e ends up with two observations. I assume this is a mistake?

Comment: Mike values will always be 1, because there's always one obs per year. iod, no, that's something that can happen if there are 4 years but the number of observations is not multiple of 4. Which just added complexity to the problem.

Comment: What? You said you wanted *one* observation per individual. What does the number of observations being a multiple of four or not? I don't get the question. And are only "1"s considered observations?

Comment: Yes, I should probably have explained better, I'll edit it. There's also a mistake in the "output" image. Only the 1s are observations, where there's a 0 there's no observation from that individual that year. And yes, I want 1 observation (one 1) from each individual, but in a way that I end up with the same (or a similar) number of observations (of 1s) each year (i.e. in a way that rowSums from the resulting matrix would be c(3, 2, 3, 3) but colSums would be c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

Comment: Check out my edited post. I think it may be more helpful.

Comment: I have run the code you copied from my answer after your example data and do not get the error you report.

Comment: Then there must be a step you're doing in between, because the in the left.join step "Year" is indeed missing from the RHS, which is year.weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code. Maybe not so elegant, but it's a start:

```
new_mat = function(df, max_iter = 100){
    ind_names <- df[,1]
    df <- df[,-1]
    n = NROW(df)
    k = NCOL(df)
    max_col = ceiling(n / k)
    resample = function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
    one_hot = function(i, n){
        x = double(n)
        x[i] = 1
        return (x)
        }
    counter = 0
    flag = TRUE
    while (flag && counter <= max_iter){
        counter = counter + 1
        out = matrix(0, n, k)
        weights = rep(max_col, k)
        index = sample(1:n)
        c2 = 0
        for (i in index){
            ind = which(df[i,] == 1)
            probs = weights[ind]
            if (max(probs) == 0)
                break
            out[i,] = one_hot(resample(ind, size = 1, prob = probs), k)
            weights = weights - out[i,]
            c2 = c2 + 1
            }
        if (c2 == length(index))
            flag = FALSE
        }
    if (flag)
        stop('No matrix found. Try again.')
    final <- cbind(ind_names, as.data.frame(out))
    names(final) <- c("ind", names(df))
    return (final)
    }
```

Requiring each column to have (roughly) the same number of occurrences poses quite a problem if you also want to randomize which column is selected. This is especially a problem when not all rows have observations present in each column. There is an implied dependence from row to row, which is probably not desirable.

Basically, this eventually sets a column's weight of being selected down to zero, once that column as reached `max_col`, or the maximum number of occurrences after which the columns cannot have roughly the same amount. (I borrowed earch's idea of weighting the columns.)

If a problem occurs (e.g. no column can be selected for the next row which has `weight>0`), then the process is re-run, up to a maximum of `max_iter`, but going through a different order of the rows.

A major drawback of this is having to repeatedly loop through all the rows. I'm not sure of a way around this given your constraints. So if you have a really large data frame, you might see some long computation times. But on the data set you provided, the function return a matrix usually after just one pass, no more than a few.

Comment: That looks promising! But it throws back an error: Error in sample.int(length(x), ...) : invalid first argument
Called from: sample.int(length(x), ...) when running the last line

Comment: I'm not getting any error when I run the code exactly as above (and using your `df` assignment). How are you calling that last line?

Comment: That works beautifully! It doesn't find a matrix if the number of 1s in each column are too variable so there is no feasible solution that will give a similar number of observations per column, but otherwise it's great. I've made some minor edits to your code to avoid the "ind" column being taken by the one_hot function as a column with data, and accepted your answer. Many thanks!

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a random Year that was 1 for each individual, then here is a dplyr/tidyr method:

```
> df <- data.frame(Ind   = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"),
+                  Year1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
+                  Year2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
+                  Year3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
+                  Year4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
> 
> year.weights <- df %>% 
+   gather(Year, Obs, -Ind) %>% 
+   group_by(Year) %>% 
+   summarize(wt = sum(Obs)) %>% 
+   ungroup
> 
> year.weights
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Year     wt
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Year1     7
2 Year2     5
3 Year3     7
4 Year4     7
> 
> 
> df %>% 
+   gather(Year, Obs, -Ind) %>%
+   filter(Obs == 1) %>% 
+   left_join(year.weights, by = "Year") %>% 
+   group_by(Ind) %>% 
+   sample_n(1, weight = 1 / wt) %>% 
+   select(-wt) %>% 
+   spread(Year, Obs) %>% 
+   ungroup
# A tibble: 11 x 5
   Ind   Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         1    NA    NA    NA
 2 b        NA    NA     1    NA
 3 c        NA     1    NA    NA
 4 d         1    NA    NA    NA
 5 e        NA    NA     1    NA
 6 f         1    NA    NA    NA
 7 g        NA    NA    NA     1
 8 h        NA    NA    NA     1
 9 i        NA    NA    NA     1
10 j        NA     1    NA    NA
11 k        NA    NA    NA     1
```

Comment: I didn't know of this tidyr method to randomly sample, thanks! However, the key point to this was to sample in a way that all columns (Years) would have an equal (or closest to equal possible) number of selected observations.

Comment: Then you want to weight each column. Answer has been edited as example

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution replacing with NAs at random 3 years out 4 per subject

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
    df[i,c(sample(2:5,3))]<-NA
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m   <- df[-1]
IND <- rowSums(m) > 0
m[] <- NA
m[cbind(which(IND),max.col(df[-1])[IND])] <- 1
cbind(df[1],m)
```

result:

```
#   Ind Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4
#1    a     1    NA    NA    NA
#2    b    NA    NA     1    NA
#3    c    NA    NA     1    NA
#4    d    NA    NA     1    NA
#5    e    NA    NA     1    NA
#6    f     1    NA    NA    NA
#7    g    NA    NA    NA     1
#8    h    NA    NA    NA     1
#9    i    NA    NA    NA     1
#10   j    NA     1    NA    NA
#11   k    NA    NA     1    NA
```

---

if you don't like to stack variables to global environement simply:

```
(function(df){
    m   <- df[-1]
    IND <- rowSums(m) > 0
    m[] <- NA
    m[cbind(which(IND),max.col(df[-1])[IND])] <- 1
    cbind(df[1],m)
})(df)   # run this n-times
```

Comment: That works nicely, but the key point was to subset in a way that I get an equal number of selected observations for each column, or at least as equal as possible (in my example it wasn't possible because there were 11 obs and 4 years). I don't even know if what I'm asking is possible

Comment: @VirginiaMoreraPujol the 12th column was due to my modified data. I tested the case that no `1` was present. I don't understand you last remark. This solution should give you the desired result. If not please provide data and output where this fails.

Comment: I can't put the output in a comment, but with the exact same data of my example, and running your code on it I get an output that has just 1 selected observation for Year1, 1 for Year2, 4 for Year3 and and 5 for Year4. At least the first time. I get a different output everytime I run it, but it doesn't guarantee a similar number of 1 in every year-

Comment: You can edit and update your post. Make sure you df is "fresh" the first time you run the code: